# getting a number from a website

Tags: vba, excel, dom, web-scraping, children

I´m trying to get the number part of an Euro amount string from a website. I tried different thing things, that normally work. here are my 3 best attempts. nothing worked

[image]

My first attempt:

```
Sub gsellor() 
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 
    Dim HTMLtags As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLtag As IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLPreisTag As IHTMLElement

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate "https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


    Set HTMLPreisTag = objIE.document.getElementById("page_content").Children(0).Children(1).Children(0).Children(1).Children(0)
    Debug.Print HTMLPreisTag.className
    Debug.Print HTMLPreisTag.Children(1).Children(0).Children(0).innerText     ' gets stuck right here



    objIE.Quit

End Sub
```

the immediate window shows:

```
MarketInfo_market-info_3lkUj
```

My second attempt:

```
Sub gsellor()  
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 
    Dim HTMLtags As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLtag As IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLPreisTag As IHTMLElement

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate "https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


    Set HTMLtags = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
    Debug.Print HTMLtags.Length
    For Each HTMLtag In HTMLtags
        Debug.Print "name: " & HTMLtag.className
        Debug.Print "text: " & HTMLtag.innerText

    Next HTMLtag


    objIE.Quit

End Sub
```

the immediate window shows:

```
 3
name: 
text: 
name: AccountPanel_account-panel-user-name_2TNIL
text: 
name: sr-only
text: Toggle navigation
```

My third attempt:

```
Sub gsellor()   
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 
    Dim HTMLtags As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLtag As IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLPreisTag As IHTMLElement

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate "https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


    Set HTMLtags = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs")
    Debug.Print HTMLtags.Length
    For Each HTMLtag In HTMLtags
        Debug.Print "name: " & HTMLtag.className
        Debug.Print "text: " & HTMLtag.innerText

    Next HTMLtag


    objIE.Quit

End Sub
```

immediate window:

```
0
```

Comment: You only need that one number, and it is *always* preceded by [this tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uznDK.png), correct?  If so, don't bother parsing it as an HTML Object, just put the `InnerHTML` in a string variable and use common text functions (like `InStr` and `Mid`) to find what you need.  There are likely dozens of examples on this site and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the content you need to make your browser wait until the content is not nothing. This is another way to serve the same purpose:

```
Sub gsellor()
    Dim ObjIE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim Ohtml As HTMLDocument
    Dim item_price As Object

    With ObjIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set Ohtml = .document
    End With

    Do
        Set item_price = Ohtml.getElementsByClassName("MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs")(0)
        DoEvents
    Loop While item_price Is Nothing

    MsgBox item_price.innerText

    ObjIE.Quit
End Sub
```